# Как выводить данные интерактивно на диалоге?

Tags: 1с

Задача: на мониторе нужно выводить окно с готовыми заказами с небольшой задержкой.
На диалоге сделал надпись, заполняю ее циклом, что-то вроде:

```
Для Каждого Строка из ТекЗаказ.Товары Цикл

        Если ЗначениеЗаполнено(Строка.ДатаПриготовления) Тогда
            КонДата = ТекущаяДата() + 3;
            Пока ТекущаяДата() < КонДата Цикл

                ЭлементыФормы.НадписьБольшая.Видимость = Истина;
                ЭлементыФормы.НадписьБольшая.Шрифт =Новый Шрифт(ЭлементыФормы.НадписьБольшая.Шрифт, , 36);
                ЭлементыФормы.НадписьБольшая.Заголовок = ЭлементыФормы.НадписьБольшая.Заголовок + Символы.ПС + "готовий";
                ЭлементыФормы.НадписьБольшая.ЦветФона=ЦветГотово;
            КонецЦикла;
        Иначе
            ЭлементыФормы.НадписьБольшая.Видимость = Ложь;
        КонецЕсли;
    КонецЦикла;
```

Но пришел к осознанию, что я так просто перезапишу данные и в коне останется лишь последняя позиция интерации цикла.

Как можно выбранные циклом готовые заказы показывать на диалоговом коне интерактивно с задержкой на отображение? Т.е. я отобрал циклом строки блюд имеющие даты приготовления и выводить их на экране поштучно с задержкой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте обработчики ожидания, например:

```
Процедура ПриОткрытии()

    // реквизиты формы
    // ТекущийИндексСтроки - тип Число
    // ТаблицаДанных - тип ТаблицаЗначений

    ПодключитьОбработчикОжидания("ОбновлениеДанных", 3);

КонецПроцедуры

Процедура ОбновлениеДанных()

    Если НЕ ТаблицаДанных.Количество() Тогда
        Возврат;
    КонецЕсли;

    ТекущийИндексСтроки = ?(ТекущийИндексСтроки = ТаблицаДанных.Количество() - 1, 0, ТекущийИндексСтроки + 1);
    ДанныеСтроки = ТаблицаДанных[ТекущийИндексСтроки];
    // ВывестиДанныеСтроки(ДанныеСтроки);

КонецПроцедуры
```